# C# ICodeCompiler - running a class

Tags: c#

I've just discovered the .NET ICodeCompiler (be aware that I know nothing about it, except that it can run programs within a program). How would I go about writing a scripting architecture around this?

Ideally, I would like the user to write some code that derives from an interface. This interface would be defined by me within my program (it cannot be edited by the user). The user would implement it, and the CompileEngine would run it. My program would then call the various methods they have implemented. Is this feasible?

eg. They would have to implement this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
  void DoSomething();
}
```

I would then compile their implementation and instantiate their object:

```
// Inside my binary
IFoo pFooImpl = CUserFoo;
pFooImpl.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible but **BEWARE!!** 
Everytime you compile the code, it gets compiled as an assembly and loaded into memory. If you change the "script" code and re-compile, it will be loaded again as another assembly. This can cause "memory leak" (although it is not a real leak) and there is no way to unload those unused assemblies.

The only solution is to **create another AppDomain** and load that assembly in that AppDomain and then unload if the code changes and do it again. But it is way more difficult to do.

**UPDATE**

For compiling have a look here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Then you would have to load the assembly using **Assembly.LoadFrom**.

```
    // assuming the assembly has only ONE class
    // implementing the interface and method is void 
    private static void CallDoSomething(string assemblyPath, Type interfaceType, 
        string methodName, object[] parameters)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        Type t = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.GetInterfaces().Count(y=>y==interfaceType)>0).FirstOrDefault();
        if (t == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No type implements this interface");
        }
        MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == methodName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (mi == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No such method");
        }
        mi.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(t), parameters);
    }
```

Comment: Please Do. I'm also wondering if this will propagate any interfaces I design in my code into the user design code.

Comment: In that link above, would it be possible to derive th 'HelloWorldClass' class from interface IFoo, which is defined in my code? Because From what Understand, the user defined code is in a different module then mine and does not have access to any of my interfaces.

Comment: You mentioned that there is a problem with compiling in this manner. If I had many source files and I compiled them one-by-one, would that result in many new Assemblies being created or just one big one?

Comment: Will result in many big assemblies. By the way, my code allows for even type of the interface defined at runtime so it uses reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, I think CodeDom and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx(v=VS.80).aspx) could help you. Is it what you're looking for?